# Homemade Dill for Charity

Tags: flavor, spices, italian-cuisine, spaghetti

I really want to make my own dill to put in my spaghetti sauce for a charity luncheon I'm hosting.

Do you fellas/ladies have any tips? How should I get started? And the middle? What about the end?

Comment: Dill is a herb which grows in soil, you don't "make" dill.

Comment: If you're asking for tips about growing your own dill, you should be asking on the gardening site : https://gardening.stackexchange.com .  If you're asking about making dill pickles, this is the right site, but I've never seen them used in spaghetti sauce.  (although maybe in a pasta salad ... but I wouldn't use spaghetti or other strand noodle for that)

Comment: Please don't think me rude or unkind **and** if you're referring to a tomato sauce for your spaghetti dish, I wouldn't eat it if it had dill in it. I love dill and use it a lot. Plus I don't think anyone should be fixated on only certain herbs for certain dishes. But (for me), putting dill in a typical spaghetti tomato sauce sounds very uninviting. (I have very open tastes in foods.) ***If*** it's not a tomato sauce, please post what kind of sauce you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from how you phrased your question you're asking how you should get started in making your sauce with dill - not how to grow it but when to add it. I have no idea what kind of sauce your making. Rather than long sphaghetti strands, consider using another pasta shape. Personally, I love rotini, the corkscrew shaped pasta.

The flavour of dill can overwhelm other flavours easily. This is most noticeable if the dish is served hot but less so if the dish is cold like a potato salad. If the sauce is meant to be served hot, it's best to add it near the end of your cooking. Make sure you snip it, or if its dried crumble it, into tiny pieces so it blends in. Better than someone taking a mouthful with a larger piece in it. If you add it to your sauce too soon, the dill could easily overwhelm other ingredients you use.

A somewhat different flavour can be achieved by lightly frying larger pieces of dill in a little oil. Don't cover the pan and keep an eye on its progress. You want the dill crisp but not burnt. When you take it out, place it on a paper towel and pat any oil off. Then you can crumble it in the dish close to the end of cooking or even over the sauce as it's served to each person. Crisp fried dill still tastes like dill but much more subtle with a lovely flavour that's hard to describe.

Answer (score 2):

You can grow dill if you want to (will take some time), or buy some fresh dill from your preferred supermarket (or farmer's market)